# Application is working as expected but when i conterize app with Docker it cannot access Cassandra container

Tags: java, spring, docker, cassandra, docker-compose

I got a problem with my application. Everything has been working fine till I conterized App with Docker.

1. I Have Docker container with Cassandra instance in there `docker run -p 9042:9042 --name cassandra cassandra:latest`

*When I run my app in IntelliJ  or run by cmd `java -jar myjar.jar` it works fine. The problem occurs when
I trying to use Docker or Docker-compose to start the app `docker run -p 8080:8080 --name api {image here}` or `docker-compose up`

**Docker File:**

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY . /target/myjar.jar 
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","target/myjar.jar"]
```

**Docker-Compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
      ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      depends-on:
      -cassandra
  cassandra:
    container_name 'cassandra'
    image: cassandra
    ports:
    - "9042:9042"
```

**What I have tried to solve the problem:**

- changing application ports
- building docker and docker-compose file in diffrent way.

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=message
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=create_if_not_exists
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=127.0.0.1
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
```

**the error when I try to run container from image (Fragment)**

```
2020-06-13 11:42:53.320  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-13 11:42:53.379  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 51ms. Found 0 Reactive Cassandra repository interfaces.
2020-06-13 11:42:53.387  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-13 11:42:53.406  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 18ms. Found 1 Cassandra repository interfaces.
2020-06-13 11:42:54.030  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-06-13 11:42:54.050  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-13 11:42:54.050  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-06-13 11:42:54.146  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-13 11:42:54.146  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1734 ms
2020-06-13 11:42:54.611  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.d.o.d.i.core.DefaultMavenCoordinates   : DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.6.1
2020-06-13 11:42:55.364  INFO 1 --- [     s0-admin-0] c.d.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock  : Using native clock for microsecond precision
2020-06-13 11:42:55.371  INFO 1 --- [     s0-admin-0] c.d.o.d.i.core.metadata.MetadataManager  : [s0] No contact points provided, defaulting to /127.0.0.1:9042
2020-06-13 11:42:55.567  WARN 1 --- [     s0-admin-1] c.d.o.d.i.c.control.ControlConnection    : [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=530346a1), trying next node (ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException))
2020-06-13 11:42:55.586  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageApi' defined in URL [jar:file:/asrecruitment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/mycompany/asrecruitment/api/MessageApi.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageService' defined in URL [jar:file:/asrecruitment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/mycompany/asrecruitment/service/MessageService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageRepo' defined in com.mycompany.asrecruitment.repository.MessageRepo defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on CassandraRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableCassandraRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=530346a1): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)]
2020-06-13 11:42:55.590  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-06-13 11:42:55.613  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-13 11:42:55.636 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageApi' defined in URL [jar:file:/asrecruitment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/mycompany/asrecruitment/api/MessageApi.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageService' defined in URL [jar:file:/asrecruitment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/mycompany/asrecruitment/service/MessageService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageRepo' defined in com.mycompany.asrecruitment.repository.MessageRepo defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on CassandraRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableCassandraRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=530346a1): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at com.mycompany.asrecruitment.app.main(app.java:12) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [asrecruitment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) [asrecruitment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [asrecruitment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [asrecruitment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageService' defined in URL [jar:file:/asrecruitment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/mycompany/asrecruitment/service/MessageService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageRepo' defined in com.mycompany.asrecruitment.repository.MessageRepo defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on CassandraRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableCassandraRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=530346a1): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageRepo' defined in com.mycompany.asrecruitment.repository.MessageRepo defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on CassandraRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableCassandraRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=530346a1): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spr
```

** Proper run `java -jar` **

```
2020-06-13 13:35:19.461  INFO 12088 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-13 13:35:19.593  INFO 12088 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 116ms. Found 0 Reactive Cassandra repository interfaces.
2020-06-13 13:35:19.609  INFO 12088 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-13 13:35:19.630  INFO 12088 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 23ms. Found 1 Cassandra repository interfaces.
2020-06-13 13:35:21.111  INFO 12088 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-06-13 13:35:21.134  INFO 12088 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-13 13:35:21.134  INFO 12088 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-06-13 13:35:21.296  INFO 12088 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-13 13:35:21.296  INFO 12088 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3376 ms
2020-06-13 13:35:21.945  INFO 12088 --- [           main] c.d.o.d.i.core.DefaultMavenCoordinates   : DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.6.1
2020-06-13 13:35:22.985  INFO 12088 --- [     s0-admin-0] c.d.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock  : Using native clock for microsecond precision
2020-06-13 13:35:22.985  INFO 12088 --- [     s0-admin-0] c.d.o.d.i.core.metadata.MetadataManager  : [s0] No contact points provided, defaulting to /127.0.0.1:9042
2020-06-13 13:35:23.961  INFO 12088 --- [        s0-io-0] c.d.o.d.i.core.channel.ChannelFactory    : [s0] Failed to connect with protocol DSE_V2, retrying with DSE_V1
2020-06-13 13:35:23.979  INFO 12088 --- [        s0-io-1] c.d.o.d.i.core.channel.ChannelFactory    : [s0] Failed to connect with protocol DSE_V1, retrying with V4
2020-06-13 13:35:24.387  INFO 12088 --- [        s0-io-2] c.d.oss.driver.api.core.uuid.Uuids       : PID obtained through native call to getpid(): 12088
2020-06-13 13:35:26.186  INFO 12088 --- [     s1-admin-0] c.d.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock  : Using native clock for microsecond precision
2020-06-13 13:35:26.186  INFO 12088 --- [     s1-admin-0] c.d.o.d.i.core.metadata.MetadataManager  : [s1] No contact points provided, defaulting to /127.0.0.1:9042
2020-06-13 13:35:26.214  INFO 12088 --- [        s1-io-0] c.d.o.d.i.core.channel.ChannelFactory    : [s1] Failed to connect with protocol DSE_V2, retrying with DSE_V1
2020-06-13 13:35:26.231  INFO 12088 --- [        s1-io-1] c.d.o.d.i.core.channel.ChannelFactory    : [s1] Failed to connect with protocol DSE_V1, retrying with V4
2020-06-13 13:35:30.078  INFO 12088 --- [     s2-admin-0] c.d.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock  : Using native clock for microsecond precision
2020-06-13 13:35:31.698  INFO 12088 --- [     s2-admin-0] c.d.o.d.i.core.metadata.MetadataManager  : [s2] No contact points provided, defaulting to /127.0.0.1:9042
2020-06-13 13:35:31.720  INFO 12088 --- [        s2-io-0] c.d.o.d.i.core.channel.ChannelFactory    : [s2] Failed to connect with protocol DSE_V2, retrying with DSE_V1
2020-06-13 13:35:31.732  INFO 12088 --- [        s2-io-1] c.d.o.d.i.core.channel.ChannelFactory    : [s2] Failed to connect with protocol DSE_V1, retrying with V4
2020-06-13 13:35:32.618  INFO 12088 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-13 13:35:32.943  INFO 12088 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-06-13 13:35:32.946  INFO 12088 --- [           main] com.mycompany.asrecruitment.app          : Started app in 16.206 seconds (JVM running for 17.064)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting. And openjdk version is? is it a typo that the version field is empty?

Comment: What are your connection properties to connect to cassandra (especially the host name)?

Comment: oh, its a typo I made when creating this post. java version is 8.

Comment: I have posted connection props and error msg below

Comment: Both containers cannot access each other unless you create a bridge network 
https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: This line clearly says that what the problem is. 
-----
nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses-
--

Comment: Thanks for answer Beast, I'll check that now

Comment: ```version: "3.8"

services:

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - mynet
    restart: always        
  
  db:
    image: cassandra
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
        - "9042:9042"

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge```
sorry, I don't know how to add docker-compose file  correctly but I have the same error when I used net for both containers

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your application isn't connecting with the Cassadra's DB image.

> 2020-06-13 11:42:55.567  WARN 1 --- [     s0-admin-1]
> c.d.o.d.i.c.control.ControlConnection    : [s0] Error connecting to
> Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=530346a1), trying
> next node (ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...]
> Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send
> request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException))

Fist, in your `docker-compose.yml`, you need to create an environment variable to be the cassandra host and then set your `application.properties`.

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
      ports:
      - "8086:8080"
      depends-on:
      -cassandra
  cassandra:
    container_name 'cassandra'
    image: cassandra
    ports:
      - "9044:9042"
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_HOST=cassandra
```

P.S. You can change the first port number to not confuse, but it's not a mistake.

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=message
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=create_if_not_exists
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=${CASSANDRA_HOST}
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
```

It is important to check the cluster's name (`spring.data.cassandra.cluster = <name>`) in the cassandra.yaml inside the cassandra's image. It should be the same as in your application's image.